# How can I make use of the $scale function in QGIS data defined properties?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS 2.0 I can use with success the $scale function in the labeling expressions.

When I tried to use it for symbolizing in the data defined properties it has a value of 0.

Is there a way to make it perform like it does in labeling (getting the scale)?

As I saw in the expression string builder help that

```
$scale function
Returns the current scale of the map canvas. 
Note: This function is only available in some contexts and will be 0 otherwise.
```

is there a source where I can read more about this e.g. in what contexts it is available?
Thanks, Tudor

Comment: Have you tried using it because the dialog will show 0 even if it is used when the expression is evaluated.  It will show 0 just because the dialog doesn't know about the map canvas so it can't get the scale at that point (to be fixed)

Comment: I have tried using it without success.

Comment: Could you share your expression that you used for scaling labels?

Comment: CASE WHEN $scale > 500 THEN ..END..

Comment: The sintaxis is similar to used in raster calculator.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in to use directly with a wrong sintaxis expression.

When I put only **$scale** in the browser I got:

[image]

By using the rule **($scale <= 500)*$scale**; where the sintaxis is similar to used in raster calculator. In the image below the rule is not reached (**$scale <= 500 = FALSE = 0**):

[image]

When the rule is reached the scale (**$scale <= 500 = TRUE = 1**) is displayed if it is used the adequate product; **($scale <= 500)*$scale**:

[image]

It works.